# eclipse cannot import apache tika src

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, apache-tika

trying to minimize/strip down the source of apache tika to be able to compile in android, since some classes I don't need and not available in android.

the problem is eclipse does not able to recognize the apache tika src as project and so cannot import.

try using file system as import but it needs root folder so cannot be done.

I do realize it needs .project and .classpath but should I add these two files to each apache tika src folder or is there a better way?

Comment: is the tika project still compilable after deleting the not needed files??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Tika is a Maven project (since there's a `pom.xml` file). So you can import it either with `File > Open Projects from Filesystem...` or `File > Import > Existing Maven projects...`.